# MS Application Insights - Sql Dependencies error code 208

Tags: entity-framework, azure-application-insights

What does error `208` means? the query:

```
dependencies
| where type == "SQL" and success == "False"
| summarize count() by resultCode
```

is giving me 4500+ itens on the last hour alone and I can't seem to find any solid documentation about this.

Details:

- The frequency of error rises as concurrency rises, meaning 1000 concurrent requests will generate more erros than 1000 sequential ones.
- My application is Asp.Net MVC 4 framework 4.6 using latest EF
- The error is intermittent. Performing a certain operation won't definitely result in the error
- I don't think that this error means "Invalid Object Name" (as per other threads) because i can see EF auto-retrying this and eventually it goes through and the whole request is successfully returned (otherwise i would have A LOT of missed phone calls...)
- The error occurs on both ASYNC and sync requests

Comment: can you please paste entire error

Comment: @TheGameiswar "ResultCode 208" is all the info I get... i'm deeply frustrated by it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in touch with MS support and according to them, this is caused by entity framework. Apparently EF keeps looking for 2 tables (migrationsHistory and edmMetadata) that I deliberately deleted. although that makes sense, i don't know why that error does not present itself on our in-house tests (the table are not present on the in-house dev env too...)

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct however Id like to add additional information:
You need to have MigrationHistory table and it has to be populated correctly. edmMetadata is old table which was replaced by MigrationHistory so no need to worry about that.

Just by adding MigrationHistory tabled did not solve the issue completely ( I was down to 3 exceptions 208 from 5 ).

However, keep in mind that populating MigrationHistory table will render your dbContext out of sync if latest migration is not inserted in MigrationHistory!

Best way to get this is to issue: 
UpdateDatabase -script 
command and copy CREATE/INSERT/UPDATE statements from there.